# Laravel 9 password.confirm middleware feature not working

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, middleware, laravel-9

I am trying to use the password.confirm middleware in some of my routes which I need to be secured. I want a user should confirm his password when he generate a specific post request.

Also,  password.confirm middleware is added $routeMiddleware property in the app/Http/Kernel.php file.

This is what my route looks like in web.php.

```
Route::post('fetchResult', [ReportController::class, 'fetchResult'])->name('fetchComplaintResult')->middleware('password.confirm');
```

But it is not working. When I generate post request it directly hit to controller fetchResult method as usual.

My controller function:

```
public function fetchResult(Request $request)
{
        Model::create([
            'id' => $request->id,
            'action' => $request->action,
            'comments' => $request->comment
        ]);
       // Other Action
}
```

Am I missing something ??

Comment: Before `Model::create([...]);`, can you put `dd(time() - session('auth.password_confirmed_at', 0));`? The `password.confirm` middleware by default will only work if this value is more than 10800. Meaning every time the password is confirmed, it's good for another 3 hours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get prompted to confirm your password every time you should write your route like this:

```php
Route::post('fetchResult', [ReportController::class, 'fetchResult'])
    ->name('fetchComplaintResult')
    ->middleware('password.confirm:password.confirm,1');
```

---

## Why?

The `password.confirm` middleware maps to the `Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\RequirePassword` class. This is its code.

```php
use Closure;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Routing\ResponseFactory;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Routing\UrlGenerator;

class RequirePassword
{
    /**
     * The response factory instance.
     *
     * @var \Illuminate\Contracts\Routing\ResponseFactory
     */
    protected $responseFactory;

    /**
     * The URL generator instance.
     *
     * @var \Illuminate\Contracts\Routing\UrlGenerator
     */
    protected $urlGenerator;

    /**
     * The password timeout.
     *
     * @var int
     */
    protected $passwordTimeout;

    /**
     * Create a new middleware instance.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Routing\ResponseFactory  $responseFactory
     * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Routing\UrlGenerator  $urlGenerator
     * @param  int|null  $passwordTimeout
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(ResponseFactory $responseFactory, UrlGenerator $urlGenerator, $passwordTimeout = null)
    {
        $this->responseFactory = $responseFactory;
        $this->urlGenerator = $urlGenerator;
        $this->passwordTimeout = $passwordTimeout ?: 10800;
    }

    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @param  string|null  $redirectToRoute
     * @param  int|null  $passwordTimeoutSeconds
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $redirectToRoute = null, $passwordTimeoutSeconds = null)
    {
        if ($this->shouldConfirmPassword($request, $passwordTimeoutSeconds)) {
            if ($request->expectsJson()) {
                return $this->responseFactory->json([
                    'message' => 'Password confirmation required.',
                ], 423);
            }

            return $this->responseFactory->redirectGuest(
                $this->urlGenerator->route($redirectToRoute ?? 'password.confirm')
            );
        }

        return $next($request);
    }

    /**
     * Determine if the confirmation timeout has expired.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int|null  $passwordTimeoutSeconds
     * @return bool
     */
    protected function shouldConfirmPassword($request, $passwordTimeoutSeconds = null)
    {
        $confirmedAt = time() - $request->session()->get('auth.password_confirmed_at', 0);

        return $confirmedAt > ($passwordTimeoutSeconds ?? $this->passwordTimeout);
    }
}
```

The important parts to note are the `handle` method's signature:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $redirectToRoute = null, $passwordTimeoutSeconds = null)
```

Here, `$redirectToRoute` and `$passwordTimeoutSeconds` are arguments we can set in the route file.

`$redirectToRoute` is used like this in the `handle` method:

```
$this->urlGenerator->route($redirectToRoute ?? 'password.confirm')
```

`$passwordTimeoutSeconds` is used here in the `shouldConfirmPassword` method.

```
return $confirmedAt > ($passwordTimeoutSeconds ?? $this->passwordTimeout);
```

Since it's set to `null`, the value `$confirmedAt` is compared to is `$this->passwordTimeout`, which is set in the constructor to 10800. (10800 seconds = 180 minutes = 3 hours).

So in summary we need to set the `$passwordTimeoutSeconds` parameter. Since it's the second parameter, we also need to set the `$redirectToRoute` parameter.

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/middleware#middleware-parameters

Comment: Route::post('fetchResult', [ReportController::class, 'fetchResult']) ->name('fetchComplaintResult') ->middleware('password.confirm:shutdown.anotherTask,1'); 
This works fine but it redirect to shutdown.anotherTask route after confirm password but I cannot capture post data there--- How can I pass post request data to shutdown.anotherTask route after password confirmation successfully done ?